# Generating odd numbers with specificaly exchanged even numbers

Tags: c++, for-loop, number-formatting

for short I didnt code for so long I forgot how to code in cpp (Im disapointed in myself...)

So the point is I want to print 4 page (A6) per sheet both sided on A4 paper. While I need to leave page number correct on the other side. So to do it I need to write specific page numbers (for example for A4: 1,3,5,7,4,2,8,6, to print it correctly).

While generate odd numbers is eazy there is problem with generating after 4 odd numbers, 4 even which must be exchanged specific ways like on example.

How can I make code for this specific problem to genetare numbers this way for document with 200 pages ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to generate anything. Just put the pattern above 1,3,5,7,4,2,8,6 into an array and use that.

For example

```
int main()
{
    static const int offset[]={1,3,5,7,4,2,8,6};
    for (int page = 0; page < 200; page += 8)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
            cout << "Page #" << page+offset[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: I will not write numbers from 1-200 this way, It wouldnt be time effective.

Comment: @Miki I'm not expecting you to write 200 numbers, see the code above.

Comment: Sry didnt saw the code, thank you.